# Write DataFrame to HDFS,connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run example from Mastering Apache Spark 2.x book.

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]
```

I am new to Spark world,but I guess that dataframe should be saved to HDFS

```
scala> df.write.json("hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/account.json")
java.net.ConnectException: Call From miki/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I checked with dfsadmin

```
 hadoop dfsadmin -safemode enter
WARNING: Use of this script to execute dfsadmin is deprecated.
WARNING: Attempting to execute replacement "hdfs dfsadmin" instead.

safemode: FileSystem file:/// is not an HDFS file system
```

jps output

```
miki@miki:~$ jps
13798 Jps
10906 SparkSubmit
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: is hadoop running locally and listening on `localhost:9000`?

Comment: How to start Hadoop locally? Take a look at my jps output.

Comment: Install hadoop and start dfs... You need a running hadoop instance to write files to an `hdfs://` file system. If you don't want to use hdfs, you can write to a `file://` path to store the file to your local file system (I think you can omit the scheme altogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your jps output, you are not running the necessary Hadoop daemons needed to read to and write from HDFS (namenode, datanode, resourcemanager). Make sure you run start-yarn and start-dfs on your machine to get your HDFS up and running.